# jQuery Isotope breaks jQuery Equal Column Heights

Tags: jquery

I've been using [jQuery Equal Column Heights](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html#example-nine) to match the main content and sidebars on my website without any problem. More to the point, I have a members directory where each person has a "more info" button that uses toggle() to expand the div and show more info. When this is clicked, I also have it trigger the equalHeightColumns() function to adjust the columns for the expanded div. Again, this works.

I've since added [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) to filter this members directory. It works, but the equalHeightColumns() function is no longer called when I hit the "more info" button. No errors show up.

My toggle(), equalHeightColumns() code:

```
    $(document).delegate('.toggle', 'click', function(){

    // get the sibling node with class 'hidden-info'
    var mysection = $(this).prev('.hidden-info');
    mysection.toggle('fast');
        $(this).html($(this).html() == '<td>LESS INFO</td>' ? '<td>MORE INFO</td>' : '<td>LESS INFO</td>');

    var fullbio = $(this).parent().parent().prev('.hidden-bio');
    fullbio.toggle();

    var partialbio = $(this).parent().parent().prev().prev('.hidden-bio');
    partialbio.toggle();

    if ( $(window).innerWidth() > 800) {
    $('#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap').css('height' , 'auto');
    $("#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap").equalHeightColumns();
    }

   else {
    $('#content, #sidebar, #content-sidebar-wrap').css('height' , 'auto');
   }

});
```

My isotope code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('.professionContainer');
$container.isotope({
    transformsEnabled: false,
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});

$('.professionFilter a').click(function(){
    $('.professionFilter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
});
});
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks.

EDIT: I realized that the equalHeightColumns function is fired if I click the link a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I needed to expand the Isotope container after toggling the entries—before adjusting the columns. So in the function, I added

```
$container.isotope('reLayout');
```

before calling `.equalHeightColumns();`